# how to use this response in Codable method in iOS swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

```
{
  "response": "success",
  "ads": {
    "imp_url": "https://github.com",
    "ad_type": "Banner Ad",
    "ad_tag": "<script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";</script>",
    "click_url": "https://github.com",
    "image_path": ""
  },
  "viewer_token": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to set response object to represent all the data in the json:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let response: String?
    let ads: Ads?
    let viewer_token: String?
}

struct Ads: Codable {
    let imp_url: String?
    let ad_type: String?
    let ad_tag: String?
    let click_url: String?
    let image_path: String?
}
```

Then you can get the data in this way:

```
func getData() {
guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: "jsonString", options: []) else {
    // Log error
    return
}
var response: Response
do {
    response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    // Do something with the response decoded
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Log error
    return
}
```

}

"jsonString" is your input.

Comment: "jsonString" is your input. -> what details need to pass here

Comment: "jsonString" is the response json string you posted above.

Comment: OK, am passed the other values, now its working, thank you

Comment: I have another question, am download the api url (.sqlite)from api call, I got the path and db informations but I dont how to retrieve the value from the .sqlite file to access ?

Comment: @Mobileteam if the answer above helped you, please rank it. For your last question please add the input, but better in new stackoverflow question, you can tag me and I will happy to help out.